# Add css code in admin_enqueue_scripts

Tags: wp-admin, admin-css

How can I add css code to `admin_enqueue_scripts`? I did this for `login_enqueue_scripts` its working fine but same thing is not working for `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

Following is my code snippet

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_css_stuff' );


function custom_css_stuff() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
    body { color: red; }
</style>

<?php
}
?>
```

This is not changing font color of body. am I missing something or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook, use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to enqueue a CSS file with the styles you want to apply.

If you want to output a `<style></style>` element use the admin_head hook to output it between the `<head></head>` tags:

```
function custom_css_stuff() {
    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { color: red; }
    </style>

    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_css_stuff' );
```

Comment: hi @jacob, Thank you for reply, I tried this code but it's not working anything else I need to do to run this code?

Comment: Make sure your CSS is actually correct. Your styles are probably being overwritten. Make sure your rules have higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the default CSS.